# performance in calling methods on AUTOWIRED objects with Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, autowired

I am using Spring 3.2 and JPA 2. I got a doubt while writing code for persisting objects in list which may be very trivial.

I am receiving list of objects from controller in service layer, and I want to persist them in database.

In case 1, I am iterating over list in dao layer and persisting object and in case 2, I am iterating over list in service layer and calling dao's method every time to persist object.

Here, I want to ask is there any performance issue related to multiple calls on AUTOWIRED object.

```
Case 1

@Service
class C1 {
    @Autowired
    SomeDAO dao;

    public void someMethod(List<SomeObject> list) {
        dao.save(list);
    }
}

@Repository
class C2 {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(List<SomeObject> list) {
        for(SomeObject obj : list) {
            entityManager.persist(obj);
        }

    }
}

CASE 2

@Service
class C1 {
    @Autowired
    SomeDAO dao;

    public void someMethod(List<SomeObject> list) {
        for(SomeObject obj : list) {
            dao.save(obj);
        }

    }
}

@Repository
class C2 {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(SomeObject obj) {
        entityManager.persist(obj);
    }
}
```

NOTE : I am still learning SPRING and this may be a silly question for some of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autowiring is happening only once at the application startup, thus it does not directly influence the performance.

However Spring might add certain functionality to your calls of @Autowired beans (or any other Spring beans) like e.g. starting/stopping DB transactions which can have performance impact on method call but on the other hand it is desirable behavior. And also the overhead is usually very small compared to business logic (eg. DB call).

Thus I would not care much about the overhead of bean calls and just focus on what do you want to achieve. E.g. I would prefer case 1 if I wanted to save all objects in one transaction (when using proper @Transactional annotation) or case 2 if I wanted to save all objects in each own transaction (e.g. I want to save all what is possible - with proper error handling)